# Rails 3 autocomplete with regular expression

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I am creating a new website that would take in instructions via text field.  In the text fields, I wanted to have a specific auto-completion mechanism work on it kind of like tab completion in a text editor.
For example, if I coded a cooking site that took in recipe steps, I would want the steps to try to auto-complete the first word based on a list of verbs (bake, cook, cutting, etc..) and then act on that intelligently by find the closet regular expression to look for what terms you should/can auto complete with after to fill in the text field.

My question is what is the best possible way I could go at this.  I was looking at tagging the items and using auto-complete on that, but wasn't sure how that would work.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way would be to use
[jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) with the callback function.

You'll want to make sure your dictionary is cached server-side so you're database isn't getting slammed with tons of requests. Memcached or Redis could come in handy for that.

You'll also want to think about how this data gets updated, what's an acceptable amount of time for the cache to be refreshed, and the model it's stored in on disk (is it used in other aspects of your program where a relational model would make more sense?).